# Python - Stripping timestamps and username from line in file

Tags: python, string, irc, text-files

I'm writing a script that will print a random line of text from a file into an XCHAT channel.  So far it works fine, but I want to add one last bit of functionality.

I have logs with, for example, "Oct 23 12:07:59 (nickname> " appearing before every line of text.  I just want to print the parts of the lines that follow the "(nickname>", how can I do this?

```
__module_name__ = "ran.py"
__module_version__ = "1.0"
__module_description__ = "script to add random text to channel messages"

import xchat
import random

def ran(message):
    message = random.choice(open("E:/logs/myfile.log", "r").readlines())
    return(message)


def ran_cb(word, word_eol, userdata):
    message = ''
    message = ran(message)
    xchat.command("msg %s %s"%(xchat.get_info('channel'), message))
    return xchat.EAT_ALL


xchat.hook_command("ran", ran_cb, help="/ran to use")
```

Answer (score 1):

If the first `>` character is exactly the place to split, then try:

```
toBeIgnored, toBeUsed = line.split('>', 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `>` can be used as separator, so:

```
_, message = message.split('>', 1)
```

will split line into 2 part, first part (underscore while it is not important) with "Oct 23 12:07:59 (nickname" and second with text after `>`

You can use it in `ran()`:

```
def ran(message):
    message = random.choice(open("E:/logs/myfile.log", "r").readlines())
    _, message = message.split('>', 1)
    return(message)
```

Comment: Where would I place this in the script?

Comment: I receive the following error when I do this:  File "D:\irc\xchat\scripts\ran.py", line 10
     _, message = message.split('>', 1)
     ^
 IndentationError: unexpected indent
 Error loading module D:\irc\xchat\scripts\ran.py

Comment: Ohh, I see. You are not the author of original code. In Python we must care about line intendation. Check if your code is intended with spaces or with tabs. All the lines in `ran()` method must be intended by equal count of spaces (for example 4 spaces) or with tab character. In my answer all is intended by 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I would have asked in the comments but I don't have enough rep. Does/Can your user's nicknames contain ">" character? If not, you can use the split command:

```
message = random.choice(open("E:/logs/myfile.log", "r").readlines())
text = message.split("> ", 1)[1]
return(text)
```

Or you can use a single line:

```
message = random.choice(open("E:/logs/myfile.log", "r").readlines()).split("> ", 1)[1]
return(message)
```

Comment: Where would I actually place this in the script?

Comment: You can use it wherever you want, however, since the reading from file happens in ran(message) function you probably want to return it there. I edited my answer.

Comment: I received the same error as I did using the other solution posted:  File "D:\irc\xchat\scripts\ran.py", line 10 _, message = message.split('>', 1) ^ IndentationError: unexpected indent Error loading module D:\irc\xchat\scripts\ran.py

Comment: It says you've indentation error, check that line, use spaces instead of tabs.